# How can I get a Right Dock on Scientific Linux 7.1?

Tags: gnome-shell, scientific-linux, panel, dock

I'd like to know how can I get a Right Dock on Scientific Linux  7.1?

I have installed Dock-to-dash which provides an excellent dock, however it is on the LHS. 
The settings options are exactly as 
https://micheleg.github.io/dash-to-dock/settings.html show in the screen shot. 
There is no option to move to the bottom or the right hand side as the description says.

I have spend 2 days trying to figure out why I cannot move it (or use any other dock). I have no preference to any docking system. I previously have used a right hand dock (gnome panel 3.2) in SL6 so I know it's possible.
I cannot install gnome-panel 3.2 or cairo-dock or docky via yum or gnome extensions. 
I have used SL 6 for the past 4 years however it was a maintained university one. This is my first 4 months of managing my own SL 7.1.

I primarily use my macbook (El Captain OS) and am keen to keep the layout for SL 7.1 as close to mac as possible, (for ease of use and efficiency, rather than aesthetic reasons).

Any advice/links to the solution?

Many Thanks in advance
Hannah

Answer (score 0):

The positioning of the dock is available from Gnome Shell 3.12, I guess Scientific Linux has 3.8. There are experimental branches "gnome-3.8-experimental" and "gnome-3.10-experimental for lower versions with some features backported on the github repository: https://github.com/micheleg/dash-to-dock. Also have a look at this discussion: https://github.com/micheleg/dash-to-dock/issues/235.

Clone the repository, checkout the desired branch

```
git clone https://github.com/micheleg/dash-to-dock.git
git checkout gnome-3.8-experimental
```

and run

```
make
make install
```

Then restart the shell.